# MySQL: исключение из SELECT повторяющихся значений определённого столбца

Tags: mysql, база-данных

В наличии таблица 'tablica' с тремя столбцами 'alfa', 'bravo' и 'charlie'. Необходимо произвести сортировку по убыванию значений 'alfa', а затем из полученной таблицы исключить повторяющиеся значения 'bravo'. Значения 'charlie' при этом должны соответствовать значениям 'alfa'. Применял:

```
SELECT MAX(alfa), bravo, charlie FROM tablica GROUP BY bravo ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Но в таком случае значения столбца 'charlie' не "синхронизируются" со значениями столбца 'alfa'.

При

```
SELECT alfa, bravo, charlie FROM tablica ORDER BY alfa DESC
```

получаю таблицу:

1. 4787 | 138 | 7
2. 4786 | 99 | 7
3. 4785 | 126 | 117
4. 4784 | 138 | 117
5. 4783 | 99 | 60
6. 4782 | 138 | 247
7. 4781 | 99 | 7
8. 4780 | 138 | 7
9. 4779 | 117 | 7
10. 4778 | 138 | 5
11. 4777 | 117 | 115
12. 4776 | 201 | 117
13. 4775 | 117 | 50
14. 4774 | 201 | 52
15. 4773 | 117 | 115
16. 4772 | 138 | 247
17. 4771 | 138 | 247
18. 4770 | 126 | 117
19. 4769 | 117 | 50
20. 4767 | 99 | 58
21. 4766 | 138 | 117
22. 4765 | 204 | 117
23. 4764 | 214 | 247
24. 4763 | 204 | 60
25. 4762 | 138 | 247

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
т.е. значению 'alfa' = '4787' соответствует значение 'charlie' = '7'.

При применении SQL-команды

```
SELECT MAX(alfa), bravo, charlie FROM tablica GROUP BY bravo ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

получаю таблицу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
т.е. значению 'alfa' = '4787' соответствует значение 'charlie' = '159'.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы значениям 'alfa' соответствовали первоначальные значения 'charlie'.

***Необходимо получить следующий результат:***

1. 4787 | 138 | 7
2. 4786 | 99 | 7
3. 4785 | 126 | 117
4. 4779 | 117 | 7
5. 4776 | 201 | 117
6. 4765 | 204 | 117
7. 4764 | 214 | 247
8. и т.д.

Версия сервера: 5.5.52-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

Comment: `SELECT MAX(alpha), bravo FROM tablica GROUP BY bravo ORDER BY 1 DESC`

Comment: @Yaant Пробовал точно также - не тот результат: https://i.imgur.com/Ysqt7Ms.png При подобном SELECT максимальное значение 'alfa' выводится 4661, а необходимо 4782.

Comment: Ну вот оно непосредственно на Ваших данных: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c7fcbf/1

Comment: почему то результат на вашей кортинке не соответствует тем исходным строкам, которые показаны в примере, поэтому невозможно судить правильный там результат или нет. запрос с max и группировкой просто обязан давать верный результат

Comment: @Yaant приношу свои извинения, я неправильно проверял. Ваш вариант на 100% работает, как отмечал.

Comment: @Yaant, в корневом вопросе я упустил дополнительные столбцы данных, чтобы не загружать лишней информацией, что оказалось ошибочным. По SQL-команде "SELECT alfa, bravo, charlie FROM tablica ORDER BY alfa DESC" получаю таблицу: https://i.imgur.com/B0O6nY4.png т.е. значению 'alfa' = '4787' соответствует значение 'charlie' = '7'. При применении SQL-команды "SELECT MAX(alfa), bravo, charlie FROM tablica GROUP BY bravo ORDER BY 1 DESC" получаю таблицу: https://i.imgur.com/9bAhkWX.png т.е. значению 'alfa' = '4787' соответствует значение 'charlie' = '159'.

Comment: @Yaant Задача состоит в том, чтобы значению 'alfa' соответствовали первоначальные значения 'charlie'.

Comment: Это очень существенное уточнение условий, добавьте его, пожалуйста, непосредственно в вопрос. И заодно, если не сложно, в текстовом виде пример исходных данных, и желаемого для этих данных результата.

Comment: @Yaant запрос в конструкторе: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb

Comment: По приведенной ссылке как-то ничего не видно, только пустые окошки. И всё-таки обновите вопрос. Я сейчас пока доеду до работы, пока там выкрою время... За это время кто-нибудь другой мог бы уже и ответить.

Comment: @Yaant отредактировал основной вопрос в соответствии Ваших комментариев.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С учетом уточнения вопроса, и в предположении, что значения `alfa` уникальны, получается нечто в таком духе:

```
SELECT t1.alfa, t1.bravo, t2.charlie FROM 
(SELECT MAX(alfa) AS alfa, bravo FROM tablica
GROUP BY bravo) AS t1
JOIN (SELECT alfa, charlie FROM tablica) AS t2
ON t1.alfa = t2.alfa
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

См. пример на [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a616c8/1).

Comment: Спасибо за полезнейшие комментарии и реактивную оперативность, Ваш SELECT я дополнил для своих нужд, проверил - всё работает так, как надо.